# Button properties not changing on click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, postback

It's probably something simple, however, the button text and enabled state don't change when the page is valid.

I have a button on the web form and the following code behind on the save click event:

```
if (Page.IsValid) {
    btnSave.Enabled = false;
    btnSave.Text = "Saving, please wait...";

    // Save method, etc...        
}
```

Comment: Are you setting the Enabled and Text properties elsewhere in the page lifecycle (e.g. in Page_Load or Page_PreRender)?

Comment: When do you want them to change? At the client right after you have run the commands (just before you start saving the item)?

Comment: @BrianDriscoll No. This is the only place!

Comment: @Markus I want them to change when the user clicks the save button and all the validation rules are met.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are first setting the Button Enabled state and Text, and then you are running your saving methods.

This all happens server-side, within the Request that was caused by the Button click. The client browser will not receive a completed Response until after your Save method has run.

If you want your Button to change before your Save method is run, you must do it client-side with JavaScript.

Comment: In this case, I assume there is a way to check if the page is valid in javascript?

Comment: I assumed you where using the ASP.NET Validators? How does the Page know it is valid?

Comment: Via a jquery script that is doing the validation.

Comment: And how does jQuery deliver the `IsValid` value into the server side Page object?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to disable users from clicking the Save button repeatedly during processing.

But the code is written on server side and the browser will only get the response at the end.
To achieve what you are trying to do, you need to disable the button on the client side.

This can be done using javascript and handling hte onClientClick event of the button.

Readup at : http://encosia.com/disable-a-button-control-during-postback/

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="BtnSubmit" 
  OnClientClick="this.disabled = true; this.value = 'Submitting...';" 
  UseSubmitBehavior="false" 
  OnClick="BtnSubmit_Click" 
  Text="Submit Me!" />
```

Note: this will work for full postbacks and not in an ajax enabled scenario.

Edit: try this

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" UseSubmitBehavior="false" 
    runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="DisableAfterValidation(this)" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

<script>
        function DisableAfterValidation(btn) {

            if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') {
                var isPageValid = Page_ClientValidate();
                if (isPageValid) {                        
                    btn.disabled = true;
                    btn.value = "please wait...";
                }
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: I had this originally, however, this disables the button regardless of validation.

Comment: Because `Page_ClientValidate` needs ASP.NET validators, not jQuery validation. It will always be true.

Comment: ah i completely missed that OP is using jQuery validation